Pinia Store caching state values
I face an issue with my Pinia store and its router guard. When I go through the 'logout' function that basically does the following, everything comes into place.
The logout function in auth.js Pinia store:
async logout() {
  this.user = null;
  this.session = null;
  this.token = null;
  this.isEmailVerified = false;

  // Clear local storage
  localStorage.removeItem('user');
  localStorage.removeItem('session');
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
  localStorage.removeItem('isEmailVerified');
  const showStore = useShowStore();
  showStore.closeMenu();
},

But when I manually remove my session from Chrome dev tools(remove the session from local storage, token, user, and isEmailVerified) Pinia does not update the state. I try to get the state from Pinia in router guards, and it still keeps the previous state, it does not go and look in local storage and gets me updated data for the session, token, etc.
Here is my auth.js Pinia store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useShowStore } from '@/store/showStore';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: 'auth',
  state: () => ({
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null,
    session: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')) || null,
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
    isEmailVerified: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isEmailVerified')) || false,
  }),
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated: () => !!localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
  },
  actions: {
    async login(email, password) {
 // ...

And the router guard:
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  //here it prints session after removing manually
  console.log('Is Authenticated:', authStore.isAuthenticated);

  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !authStore.isAuthenticated) {
    next('/SignIn'); // Redirect to SignIn if not authenticated
  } else if (to.meta.approachOnlyLoggedOut && authStore.isAuthenticated && authStore.isEmailVerified) {
    next('/'); // Redirect to dashboard if authenticated and email verified
  } else if (authStore.isAuthenticated && !authStore.isEmailVerified && to.path !== '/EmailVerification') {
    if (to.path == '/VerifyEmail') {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/EmailVerification'); // Redirect to EmailVerification if email is not verified
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

How can I get a fresh state each time? I don't want to update the state through action in the router since I will use this isAuthenticated in many places in the app, so I don't want to invoke another action before I get the state, I want this logic centralized.
I have tried many things, but it remains in its previous state.

can you format your code so it isn't a string template literal, and has some proper indentation

The localStorage is not reactive so changes would not reflect in your getters. Since the isAuthenticate does not reference reactive objects, it always returns the initial state. As a solution, add an action method with the same code. actions: { isAuthValid() { return !!localStorage.getItem('token')} and use it instead

@Raeisi Thanks for this, this was a quite good explanation and solution!

@Raeisi now issue could be that if I change the type of isAuthenticated from getter, to action, Vue cannot longer track it in a computed value in other components
const isAuthenticated = computed(() => authStore.isAuthenticated());

This article shows how to make an abstract layer over non-reactive (localStorage) objects in Vue3:  https://lorisleiva.com/gists/abstract-local-storage-in-vue-3

@Raeisi thanks a lot, this should work for me!

@MilanMilosevic take a look at the store.$reset() method, could be a way to clean your store without having to go prop by prop.
